# Is the finitely additive integral linear in probability measures?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a *finitely additive* probability space. That is, $\mu$ is assumed to be finitely, but not necessarily, countably additive.

We can define integration for non-negative extended-real functions with respect to $\mu$ in the usual way. If $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ is an $\mathcal X$ measurable step function of the form
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i 1_{A_i},$$
where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb R$ and $A_i \in \mathcal X$, let
$$\int f d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mu(A_i).$$
Then for any non-negative extended-real $\mathcal X$-measurable $f$, let
$$\int f d\mu = \sup\Big\{ \int g d \mu: 0 \leq g \leq f, g \ \text{is a step function} \Big \}.$$
The resulting integral is linear in the sense that
$$\int \alpha(f+g) d\mu = \alpha \int f d\mu + \alpha \int g d\mu$$
for all non-negative extended-real $\mathcal X$-measurable $f$ and $g$, and all $\alpha \in \mathbb R^+$.

> I'm wondering whether the dual form of linearity holds as well. That is: Is it true that for all non-negative extended-real $\mathcal X$-measurable $f$, all $\alpha \in [0,1]$, and all finitely additive probability measures $\mu_1$ and $mu_2$
> $$\int f d(\alpha \mu_1 + (1 - \alpha) \mu_2) = \alpha \int f d\mu_1 + (1-\alpha) \int f d\mu_2?\tag{1}$$

I can show that (1) is true for all bounded $f$, and for general $f$, I can show that
$$\int f d(\alpha \mu_1 + (1 - \alpha) \mu_2) \leq \alpha \int f d\mu_1 + (1-\alpha) \int f d\mu_2.$$
So all I need is the reverse inequality for general $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. I can't really see what is your problem.
I assume $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are positive.Otherwise, your finitely additive integral would behave weird.
Let $g,h$ be two positive step functions. So $u=max(g,h)$ is also a positive step function. Furthermore, if $g,h \le f$ then $u$ is also not bigger than $f$.
Hence,
$\alpha \int g d\mu_1+ (1-\alpha) \int h d\mu_2 \le \alpha \int u d\mu_1+ (1-\alpha) \int u d\mu_2 = \int u d( \alpha \mu_1+(1-\alpha)\mu_2)\le \int fd( \alpha \mu_1+(1-\alpha)\mu_2) $
So $\alpha \int f d\mu_1+ (1-\alpha) \int f d\mu_2 \le \int fd( \alpha \mu_1+(1-\alpha)\mu_2) $
On the other hand,
For all step function $0 \le g \le f$
$\int g d( \alpha \mu_1+(1-\alpha)\mu_2) = \alpha \int g d\mu_1+ (1-\alpha) \int g d\mu_2 \le  \alpha \int f d\mu_1+ (1-\alpha) \int f d\mu_2 $
So, $\alpha \int f d\mu_1+ (1-\alpha) \int f d\mu_2 \ge \int fd( \alpha \mu_1+(1-\alpha)\mu_2) $
Hence, conclusion.

Am I wrong somewhere?